# In Template - Make Value Of Model Effect The Next Models Display

Tags: django, django-templates

I have many `models`s being displayed. Each `model` has a checkbox `completed`. Over time users will 'check' these checkboxes, and they will always do this sequentially (in order: one first, then two etc..).

I want to change the class of the single `model` which comes after the last `checked` checkbox.

For example, if there are 10 checkboxes and numbers 1, 2 and 3 are 'checked', I want to change the class of the 4th checkbox.

model.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

template.html

```
# this changes the class of 'checked' checkboxes - not what I want
{% for model in user.my_model.all %}
    {% if model.completed == True %}
        <div class="panel-heading highlight">
    {% else %}
        <div class="panel-heading">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do? I don't follow. Why can't you just use a single field such as "lastcompletedstep = models.IntegerField" that tells you what step the person is on?

Comment: I have teachers and students. When a lesson is complete the teacher presses the 'completed' box on the lesson. Then when the student views their lessons the lesson they're up to is highlighted. Of course I could change the checkbox from 'completed' to 'up to' and get teachers to select the lesson the student is up to (and unselect the previous one), but I think for usability, having the teachers check-off completed lessons is a lot easier and less error prone. I could also think of other ways to do this but am trying to keep it as intuitive as possible for users.

Comment: Could you run some logic like "if last_completed == 3, then on_lesson_complete update last_completed == 4"? And then for your view, do "current_lesson == last_completed + 1"? Are all of your lessons stored in a single model, or do you have a separate model for each?